# jQuery or JavaScript equivalent of PHP strpos function to find string on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an equivalent function in JavaScript or jQuery similar to `strpos` in PHP?

I want to locate a string inside an element on a page. The string I'm looking for is:

```
td class="SeparateColumn"
```

I would like something where I can run it like this to find:

```
if $("anystring")
  then do it
```

Comment: You use the one already existing in plain Javascript?

Comment: I see, so you'd like to search an entire page for a string?

Comment: When I try to use in jQuery I get "indexOf is not a function"   Any other way to do this with javascript ? ? ?  HELP!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I assume you mean check whether a string contains a character, and the position in the string - you'd like to use the `indexOf()` method of a string in JS. Here are the [relevant docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/indexOf).

---

Okay, so you'd like to search the whole page! The `:contains()` selector will do that. See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#text) for `:contains`.

To search every element in the page, use

```
var has_string = $('*:contains("search text")');
```

If you get jQuery elements back, then the search was a success. For example, on this very page

```
var has_string=$('*:contains("Alex JL")').length
//has_string is 18
var has_string=$('*:contains("horsey rodeo")').length
//has_string if 0. So, you could an `if` on this and it would work as expected.
```

Comment: Of course, the act of including 'horsey rodeo' in the example makes the last part technically false, but we won't get into that conundrum.

Comment: sounds good; how can I check if element    <td class="SeparateColumn">  has a specific string on this page

Comment: @Tom `if($('td.SeparateColumn:contains("the string")')){/* do something*/}` should do it.

Comment: thanks but this fails: if(jQuery("tr.SeparateRow:contains('mycode')"))

Comment: @Tom fails in which way? An error, or it doesn't find the string? Oh - you have `tr.SeparateRow`, I think you mean `td.SeparateRow`.

Answer (score 47):

You don't need jquery for this -- plain old Javascript will do just fine, using the `.indexof()` method.

However if you really want an exact syntax match for PHP's strpos(), something like this would do it:

```
function strpos (haystack, needle, offset) {
  var i = (haystack+'').indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
  return i === -1 ? false : i;
}
```

Note: This function taken from here: http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos:545

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahendranmails/gzx1mnnu/1/)

Comment: IE8 and below do not support `indexOf`.

Comment: @YouBook that's Array.indexOf(), not String.indexOf(), that is not supported by older versions of IE.