# PHP functions to jQuery functions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, strpos

I have this script in PHP

```
// To prevent complications using scientific numbers less than 0 ex 7.2341232E-23
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($a, 'E-'))) { $a = 0; }

// Split $a so we only get the numbers before '.'
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($a, '.'))) { $a = substr($a, 0, $cal); }
```

I would like to know a simple way to make the same function in jQuery.. Any Ideas?

I did what you said... but before I go through and finish the rest of the script could you please tell me if this is right?

```
var a1 = a.indexOf("E-");
if (a1) { a = 0; }

var a2 = a.indexOf(".");
if (a2) { Math.floor(a); }
```

EDIT: I have now created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m54Du/) that contains the script I have created based on your help.. thank you very much.. unfortunately something doesn't seem to work right.. Can Anybody please take a look at it, and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What have you tried? I think those are quite easy transformation even using vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, cause I couldn't find anything jQuery relating to strpos.

Comment: That's because in vanilla JavaScript there is already a [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.

Comment: jQuery has no string methods ... web search `javascript string methods`

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted That's because jQuery is mostly a replacement for the DOM. It's not intended as a replacement of all of JavaScript.

Comment: I used to say "java != javascript". Now I'll have to start saying "jQuery != javascript".

Comment: Thanks everybody... So basically I don't need to look for a jQuery soluion, but a Javascript solution instead..

Comment: @Philip your example is Javascript not jQuery in the first place ;-) jQuery is never going to be the Javascript framework of choice for mathematical functionality.

Comment: @DavidBarker Thanks.. I know that :) But could you please tell me if the script is correct or wrong?

Comment: I can't see a problem with it, does it work? In theory it looks ok. As a side note you can use `.toFixed(x)` to force the number to decimal if you wanted to evaluate it mathematically rather than by string comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple.. just use this:

```
a = Math.floor(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function in my toolkit might help you out,

```
function strpos (haystack, needle, offset) {
// http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
// +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
// +   improved by: Onno Marsman
// +   bugfixed by: Daniel Esteban
// +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
// *     example 1: strpos('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'e', 5);
// *     returns 1: 14
var i = (haystack + '').indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
return i === -1 ? false : i;
}
```

Or if you want to use jQuery selectors this answer might help you

[jQuery or JavaScript equivalent of PHP strpos function to find string on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978204/jquery-or-javascript-equivalent-of-php-strpos-function-to-find-string-on-a-page)