# Get Substring between two characters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

I am trying to extract a string from within a larger string where it get everything in between a `:` and a `;`

Current

```
Str = 'MyLongString:StringIWant;'
```

Desired Output

```
newStr = 'StringIWant'
```

Comment: ('MyLongString:StringIWant;'.split(":")[1] ||"").split(";")[0]

Answer (score 681, accepted):

You can try this

```
var mySubString = str.substring(
    str.indexOf(":") + 1, 
    str.lastIndexOf(";")
);
```

Comment: Trivial solution but handy especially if you want to avoid regular expressions.

Comment: Does anyone know how I would do this for every occurence of a substring between my starting and ending string?

Comment: This doesn't cover many other cases (I think it's not so useful when solution is too specific). See the answer by tsds, it covers so many more cases.

Answer (score 229):

You can also try this:

```
var str = 'one:two;three';    
str.split(':').pop().split(';')[0]; // returns 'two'
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer because it covers many other cases such as: having multiple characters instead of just one; finding next occurance; this solved my need and the most voted answer didn't.. I had to extract version from URL: https://somewhere.com/something/version_1.2.3/somethingElse/page and this worked like a charm.

Comment: This has one setback though.. if there are no : nor ;  the whole str is returned :)

Comment: Phew! I can still keep my lambda braceless.

Comment: Works great for URLs

Answer (score 68):

Use `split()`

```
var s = 'MyLongString:StringIWant;';
var arrStr = s.split(/[:;]/);
alert(arrStr);
```

`arrStr` will contain all the string delimited by `:` or `;`
So access every string through `for-loop`

```
for(var i=0; i<arrStr.length; i++)
    alert(arrStr[i]);
```

Comment: The string I want is between [ ] and this ain't working... ex: 'MyLongString[StringIWant]'.split(/[[]]/);

Comment: @Philippe For your use-case, use this regex `\[(.*?)\]`    ---> In short you need to escape square brackets, as [ ] denotes character class in regex.

Answer (score 51):

@Babasaheb Gosavi Answer is perfect if you have one occurrence of the substrings (":" and ";"). but once you have multiple occurrences, it might get little bit tricky.

---

The best solution I have came up with to work on multiple projects is using four methods inside an object.

- **First method:** is to actually get a substring from between two strings (however it will find only one result).
- **Second method:** will remove the (would-be) most recently found result with the substrings after and before it.
- **Third method:** will do the above two methods recursively on a string.
- **Fourth method:** will apply the third method and return the result.

---

### Code

So enough talking, let's see the code:

```
var getFromBetween = {
    results:[],
    string:"",
    getFromBetween:function (sub1,sub2) {
        if(this.string.indexOf(sub1) < 0 || this.string.indexOf(sub2) < 0) return false;
        var SP = this.string.indexOf(sub1)+sub1.length;
        var string1 = this.string.substr(0,SP);
        var string2 = this.string.substr(SP);
        var TP = string1.length + string2.indexOf(sub2);
        return this.string.substring(SP,TP);
    },
    removeFromBetween:function (sub1,sub2) {
        if(this.string.indexOf(sub1) < 0 || this.string.indexOf(sub2) < 0) return false;
        var removal = sub1+this.getFromBetween(sub1,sub2)+sub2;
        this.string = this.string.replace(removal,"");
    },
    getAllResults:function (sub1,sub2) {
        // first check to see if we do have both substrings
        if(this.string.indexOf(sub1) < 0 || this.string.indexOf(sub2) < 0) return;

        // find one result
        var result = this.getFromBetween(sub1,sub2);
        // push it to the results array
        this.results.push(result);
        // remove the most recently found one from the string
        this.removeFromBetween(sub1,sub2);

        // if there's more substrings
        if(this.string.indexOf(sub1) > -1 && this.string.indexOf(sub2) > -1) {
            this.getAllResults(sub1,sub2);
        }
        else return;
    },
    get:function (string,sub1,sub2) {
        this.results = [];
        this.string = string;
        this.getAllResults(sub1,sub2);
        return this.results;
    }
};
```

---

### How to use?

#### Example:

```
var str = 'this is the haystack {{{0}}} {{{1}}} {{{2}}} {{{3}}} {{{4}}} some text {{{5}}} end of haystack';
var result = getFromBetween.get(str,"{{{","}}}");
console.log(result);
// returns: [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Getting a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` exception.

Comment: Great answer. this was just what I needed.

Comment: Getting ```this.string = this.string.replace(removal, ""); 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded```

Comment: This is the only recursive answer, nice.

Comment: Excellent recursive solution with plain JS and no regex.

Answer (score 35):

```
var s = 'MyLongString:StringIWant;';
/:([^;]+);/.exec(s)[1]; // StringIWant
```

Comment: What is the purpose of ; in [^;]

Comment: the translation is: "/" start the pattern. Match a ":" with "[]" anything of "^;" not semi-colon "+" repeatedly and then find a ";" semi-colon and "/" end the pattern.

Answer (score 32):

I like this method:

```
var str = 'MyLongString:StringIWant;';
var tmpStr  = str.match(":(.*);");
var newStr = tmpStr[1];
//newStr now contains 'StringIWant'
```

Comment: I tested this in a SharePoint 2013 Webpart and worked great if that helps anyone in the future!

Comment: This may not work if the string that you want is between "(" and ")"

Comment: @bravokeyl just escape the parenthesis. Like `str.match("\\((.*)\\)")`. So this will give you an array with 2 items. One with parenthesis and one with extracted parenthesis.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a higher order function to return a 'compiled' version of your extractor, that way it's faster.

With regexes, and compiling the regex once in a closure, Javascript's match will return all matches.

This leaves us with only having to remove what we used as our markers (ie: `{{`) and we can use string length for this with slice.

```
function extract([beg, end]) {
    const matcher = new RegExp(`${beg}(.*?)${end}`,'gm');
    const normalise = (str) => str.slice(beg.length,end.length*-1);
    return function(str) {
        return str.match(matcher).map(normalise);
    }
}
```

Compile once and use multiple times...

```
const stringExtractor = extract(['{','}']);
const stuffIneed = stringExtractor('this {is} some {text} that can be {extracted} with a {reusable} function');
// Outputs: [ 'is', 'text', 'extracted', 'reusable' ]
```

Or single-time use...

```
const stuffIneed = extract(['{','}'])('this {is} some {text} that can be {extracted} with a {reusable} function');
// Outputs: [ 'is', 'text', 'extracted', 'reusable' ]
```

Also look at Javascript's `replace` function but using a function for the replacement argument (You would do that if for example you were doing a mini template engine (string interpolation) ... lodash.get could also be helpful then to get the values you want to replace with ? ...

My answer is too long but it might help someone!

Comment: Nice.  FYI - this one didn't work if the extraction markers were also regex special chars.

Answer (score 9):

I used @tsds way but by only using the split function.

```
var str = 'one:two;three';    
str.split(':')[1].split(';')[0] // returns 'two'
```

word of caution: if therre is no ":" in the string accessing '1' index of the array will throw an error! str.split(':')[1]

therefore @tsds way is safer if there is uncertainty

```
str.split(':').pop().split(';')[0]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
function substringBetween(s, a, b) {
    var p = s.indexOf(a) + a.length;
    return s.substring(p, s.indexOf(b, p));
}

// substringBetween('MyLongString:StringIWant;', ':', ';') -> StringIWant
// substringBetween('MyLongString:StringIWant;;', ':', ';') -> StringIWant
// substringBetween('MyLongString:StringIWant;:StringIDontWant;', ':', ';') -> StringIWant
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution for strings between 2 characters

Comment: simple solution

Answer (score 9):

Generic and simple:

```js
function betweenMarkers(text, begin, end) {
  var firstChar = text.indexOf(begin) + begin.length;
  var lastChar = text.indexOf(end);
  var newText = text.substring(firstChar, lastChar);
  return newText;
}

console.log(betweenMarkers("MyLongString:StringIWant;",":",";"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for retrieving the page title in google app script.

Answer (score 5):

Use the ‘get_between’ utility function:

```
get_between <- function(str, first_character, last_character) {
    new_str = str.match(first_character + "(.*)" + last_character)[1].trim()
    return(new_str)
    }
```

**string**

```
my_string = 'and the thing that ! on the @ with the ^^ goes now'
```

**usage**:

```
get_between(my_string, 'that', 'now')
```

**result**:

```
"! on the @ with the ^^ goes
```

Answer (score 5):

This code above works for simple examples but can help ...
Using Typescript.

### Parameters

- `sentence` : the string you want to get parts of
- `first` : beginning character (for the initial example it would be `:`)
- `last` : last character of your part (for the initial example it would be `;`)

### Output

An array of string (`string[]`). Returns `[]` if no good parts in the `sentence`.

### Code

```
function getParts(sentence: string, first: string, last: string): string[] { 
  let goodParts: string[] = [];
  
  const allParts = sentence.split(first);

  allParts.forEach((part: string) => {
    if (part.indexOf(last) > -1) {
            const goodOne = (part.split(last))[0];
      goodParts = goodParts.concat(goodOne);
    }
  });
  
  return goodParts;
}
```

### Example

```
const origin = "wrongString1:rightString1;wrongString2:rightString2;wrongString3:rightString3;wrongString4:rightString4;";

const result = getParts(origin, ':', ';');

console.log(result);
// ["rightString1", "rightString2", "rightString3", "rightString4"]
```

Comment: Nice.  FYI for others ... just remove the datatypes (": string") for pure javascript.

Answer (score 3):

This could be the possible solution

```
var str = 'RACK NO:Stock;PRODUCT TYPE:Stock Sale;PART N0:0035719061;INDEX NO:21A627 042;PART NAME:SPRING;';  
var newstr = str.split(':')[1].split(';')[0]; // return value as 'Stock'

console.log('stringvalue',newstr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Get string between two substrings (contains more than 1 character)

```
function substrInBetween(whole_str, str1, str2){
   if (whole_str.indexOf(str1) === -1 || whole_str.indexOf(str2) === -1) {
       return undefined; // or ""
  }
  var strlength1 = str1.length;
  return whole_str.substring(
                whole_str.indexOf(str1) + strlength1, 
                whole_str.indexOf(str2)
               );

   }
```

Note I use `indexOf()` instead of `lastIndexOf()` so it will check for first occurences  of those strings

Comment: Nice and very readable function. But what is the purpose of the `strlength1` variable? The value should be used inline instead. Also it's not clear which [case style](https://medium.com/better-programming/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841) you are using. `strlength1` - no style, `whole_str` - snake case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this one...

```js
function extractText(str,delimiter){
  if (str && delimiter){
    var firstIndex = str.indexOf(delimiter)+1;
    var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
    str = str.substring(firstIndex,lastIndex);
  }
  return str;
}


var quotes = document.getElementById("quotes");

// &#34 - represents quotation mark in HTML
```

```html
<div>


  <div>
  
    <span id="at">
      My string is @between@ the "at" sign
    </span>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('at').innerText = extractText(document.getElementById('at').innerText,'@')">Click</button>
  
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span id="quotes">
      My string is "between" quotes chars
    </span>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('quotes').innerText = extractText(document.getElementById('quotes').innerText,'&#34')">Click</button>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to Get Substring between two characters using javascript.

```
        $("button").click(function(){
            var myStr = "MyLongString:StringIWant;";
            var subStr = myStr.match(":(.*);");
            alert(subStr[1]);
        });
```

Taken from @ [Find substring between the two characters with jQuery](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-find-substring-between-the-two-characters-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

A small function I made that can grab the string between, and can (optionally) skip a number of matched words to grab a specific index.

Also, setting `start` to `false` will use the beginning of the string, and setting `end` to `false` will use the end of the string.

set `pos1` to the position of the `start` text you want to use, `1` will use the first occurrence of `start`

`pos2` does the same thing as `pos1`, but for `end`, and `1` will use the first occurrence of `end` only after `start`, occurrences of `end` before `start` are ignored.

```
function getStringBetween(str, start=false, end=false, pos1=1, pos2=1){
  var newPos1 = 0;
  var newPos2 = str.length;

  if(start){
    var loops = pos1;
    var i = 0;
    while(loops > 0){
      if(i > str.length){
        break;
      }else if(str[i] == start[0]){
        var found = 0;
        for(var p = 0; p < start.length; p++){
          if(str[i+p] == start[p]){
            found++;
          }
        }
        if(found >= start.length){
          newPos1 = i + start.length;
          loops--;
        }
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  if(end){
    var loops = pos2;
    var i = newPos1;
    while(loops > 0){
      if(i > str.length){
        break;
      }else if(str[i] == end[0]){
        var found = 0;
        for(var p = 0; p < end.length; p++){
          if(str[i+p] == end[p]){
            found++;
          }
        }
        if(found >= end.length){
          newPos2 = i;
          loops--;
        }
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  var result = '';
  for(var i = newPos1; i < newPos2; i++){
    result += str[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all substring.

```
var out = []; 'MyLongString:StringIWant;'
.replace(/(:)\w+(;)+/g, (e) => {
    out.push(e.replace(':', '').replace(';', ''))
    return e;
});
console.log(out[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function-

```
function getStringInBetween(string, start , end) {
    // start and end will be excluded
    var indexOfStart = string.indexOf(start)
    indexOfStart = indexOfStart + start.length;
    var newString = string.slice(indexOfStart)
    var indexOfEnd = newString.indexOf(end)
    return newString.slice(0, indexOfEnd)
}
```

For ex -

```
let string = "<div class = 'mice'> I know how to code </div>"
let start = "<div class = 'mice'> "
let end = " </div>"
//then, getStringInBetween(string, start, end) returns "I know how to code"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all substrings from a string, that occur between two delimiters (different or same), you can use this function. It returns an array with all substrings found:

```
function get_substrings_between(str, startDelimiter, endDelimiter) 
{
    var contents = [];
    var startDelimiterLength = startDelimiter.length;
    var endDelimiterLength = endDelimiter.length;
    var startFrom = contentStart = contentEnd = 0;
    
    while(false !== (contentStart = strpos(str, startDelimiter, startFrom))) 
    {
        contentStart += startDelimiterLength;
        contentEnd = strpos(str, endDelimiter, contentStart);
        if(false === contentEnd) 
        {
            break;
        }
        contents.push( str.substr(contentStart, contentEnd - contentStart) );
        startFrom = contentEnd + endDelimiterLength;
    }

    return contents;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978237/1066234
function strpos(haystack, needle, offset) 
{
    var i = (haystack+'').indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
    return i === -1 ? false : i;
}

// Example usage
var string = "We want to extract all infos (essential ones) from within the brackets (this should be fun).";
var extracted = get_substrings_between(string, '(', ')');
console.log(extracted); 
// output: (2) ["essential ones", "this should be fun"]
```

Orginally from PHP by [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27078384/1066234), ported to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '[basic_salary]+100/[basic_salary]';
var arr = str.split('');
var myArr = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] == '['){
        var a = '';
        for(var j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[j] == ']'){
                var i = j-1;
                break;
            }else{
                a += arr[j];
            }
        }
        myArr.push(a);
    }
    var operatorsArr = ['+','-','*','/','%'];
    if(operatorsArr.includes(arr[i])){
        myArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    var numbArr = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    if(numbArr.includes(arr[i])){
        var a = '';
        for(var j=i;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(numbArr.includes(arr[j])){
                a += arr[j];
            }else{
                var i = j-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        myArr.push(a);
    }
}
myArr = ["basic_salary", "+", "100", "/", "basic_salary"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I just made.

Note that the function will return everything after `start` if `end` is not found after `start`. It also expects there's only one occurrence of of start and end, and if there are multiple - it will only consider the first.

License: Public domain

```
/**
 * Extracts a string from `source` that is placed between `start` and `end`. The function
 * considers only one instance of start and before, or the first instance and does not support
 * multiple occurences otherwise. If end string is not found, it will return everything after
 * `start` to the end of the string.
 */
export function stringBetween(source, start, end) {
  if (source.indexOf(start) === -1) {
    return null;
  }

  const sourceSplitByStartString = source.split(start);

  // Note: If start string is the very first occurence in source string, the result will be an
  // array where the first item is an empty string and the next item is of interest.

  if (
    sourceSplitByStartString.length === 1
    || sourceSplitByStartString[1] === ''
  ) {
    // It means that start is either the entire string or is at the very end of the string, so there
    // is not anything between
    return '';
  }

  const afterStart = sourceSplitByStartString[1];

  // If the after separator is not found, return everything after the start separator to the end
  // of the string
  if (afterStart.indexOf(end) === -1) {
    return afterStart;
  }

  const afterStartSplitByEnd = afterStart.split(end);

  if (afterStartSplitByEnd[0] === '') {
    return '';
  }

  return afterStartSplitByEnd[0];
}
```

Tests:

```
import { stringBetween } from './string';

describe('string utlities', () => {
  describe('stringBetween', () => {
    it('Extracts a substring between 2 other substrings', () => {
      const sample1 = stringBetween('Black cat climbed the tree fast.', 'cat ', ' the tree');
      expect(sample1).toBe('climbed');

      const sample2 = stringBetween('Black cat climbed the tree fast.', 'Black ', ' fast.');
      expect(sample2).toBe('cat climbed the tree');
    });

    it('extracts everything after start if end is not found', () => {
      const sample2 = stringBetween('Black cat climbed the tree fast.', 'Black ', 'not-there');
      expect(sample2).toBe('cat climbed the tree fast.');
    });

    it('returns empty string if start string occurs at the end', () => {
      const sample = stringBetween('Black cat climbed the tree fast.', 'fast.', 'climbed');
      expect(sample).toBe('');
    });

    it('returns empty string if start string is the entire string', () => {
      const sample = stringBetween('Black cat', 'Black cat', 'climbed');
      expect(sample).toBe('');
    });

    it('returns empty string if there is not anything between start and end', () => {
      const sample = stringBetween('Black cat climbed the tree fast.', 'climbed ', 'the tree');
      expect(sample).toBe('');
    });

    it('returns null if start string does not exist in the source string', () => {
      const sample = stringBetween('Black cat climbed the tree fast.', 'not-there ', 'the tree');
      expect(sample).toBe(null);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable function that allows you to make the returned substring inclusive or exclusive and optionally trim it afterwards:

```
function get_substring(full_string, substring_1, substring_2, inclusive, trim)
{
    if (full_string === null) { return null; };
    let substring_1_start = full_string.indexOf(substring_1);
    if (substring_1_start === -1 ) { return null; }
    let substring_2_start = full_string.indexOf(substring_2, substring_1_start);
    if (substring_2_start === -1 ) { return null; }
    let substring_1_end = substring_1_start + substring_1.length;
    let substring_2_end = substring_2_start + substring_2.length;
    let return_string = inclusive ? (full_string.substring(substring_1_start, substring_2_end)) : (full_string.substring(substring_1_end, substring_2_start));
    return trim ? return_string.trim() : return_string;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
//Returns 'cake and ice cream'
get_substring('I like cake and ice cream', 'cake', 'cream', true, true);

//Returns ' and ice '
get_substring('I like cake and ice cream', 'cake', 'cream', false, false);

//Returns 'and ice'
get_substring('I like cake and ice cream', 'cake', 'cream', false, true);

//Returns null
get_substring('I like cake and ice cream', 'cake', 'cookies', false, false);

//Returns null
get_substring('I like cake and ice cream', null, 'cream', false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a loop

```
const extractBetween = (str, separator) => {
let output = [];
let next_index = str.indexOf(separator)

while (next_index !== -1) {
    let after_next_index = str.indexOf(separator, next_index + separator.length)
    if (after_next_index !== -1)
        output.push(str.substring(next_index + separator.length, after_next_index))

    next_index = str.indexOf(separator, after_next_index + separator.length)

}

return output;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the simplest and likely the fastest and works with strings, not just character delimeters

```js
const result = ('MyLongString:StringIWant;'.split(":")[1] ||"").split(";")[0]
document.writeln(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic but it works. Performance isn't too bad.

```js
const findWordInText = (text, openTag, closeTag) => {
    let wordStartIndex = "", arrWord = []
    for (let i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        let char = text[i]
        if (char == openTag) wordStartIndex = i
        else if (char == closeTag) arrWord.push(text.slice(wordStartIndex+1, i))
    }
    return arrWord
}
let data = findWordInText("Where Are You [Employee Name]? your have a [Shift] shift. My name is [Name]. I'm [Year] old. I come from [Country]", "[", "]")
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Following Function gets the first match

```js
function getStringBetween(x: string, start: string, end: string) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${start}(.*?)${end}`)

  if (regex.test(x)) {
    return regex.exec(x)![1]
  } else return undefined
}
```

Jest Tests

```js
test("getStringBetween", () => {
  const result = getStringBetween("<em> Jai Ram</em>", "<em>", "</em>")
  expect(result).toEqual(" Jai Ram")
  const result1 = getStringBetween(
    "hare Jai Ram hare hare hare",
    "hare",
    "hare"
  )
  expect(result1).toEqual(" Jai Ram ")
})
```