# Get EVERY String between two words

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string, substring

I tried to make a search-bar for my current project.

Here is the current HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchbar"/>
```

The CSS is for now not important...

I made it possible to find files/folders from server:

If you hit enter, JavaScript sends a $.post()

Here is my Javascript:

```
$.post( "files/openFolder.php",{folder : $searchtext}, function() {
})
.success(function(data) {
    if(data != "") {
        if(data.indexOf("folder:") > -1){ //contains folders..!
            foundedFolders = data;
            myfolders = foundedFolders.split(/[folder:&]/);
            myfolders = cleanArray(myfolders);
            generateFolderBoxes(myfolders);
            folderBoxSettings();
        }else if(data.indexOf("file:") > -1){ // contains files..!
            foundedFiles = data;
            myfiles = foundedFiles.split(/[file:&]/);
            myfiles = cleanArray(myfiles); //cleans the Array from empty Strings.
            generateFileBoxes(myfiles);
            fileBoxSettings();  
        }

    }
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("Sorry doesn't worked, try later again.");
});
```

My problem is here:

```
myfolders = foundedFolders.split(/[folder:&]/);
```

and

```
myfiles = foundedFiles.split(/[file:&]/);
```

PHP-Output:

```
"folder:****&file:*****&file:*****&"
```

I read this stackoverflow, to get the foldernames, or file: [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript#answer-14867870)

The Reg-Expression outputs:

```
["such", " - Kop", ".txt", "such", ".txt", "t", "st - Kop", ".txt", "t", "st.txt"]
```

But normaly it should be:

```
["suche - Kopie.txt","suche.txt","test - Kopie.txt","test.txt"]
```

These "filenames" are needed to display them..

Thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is the regex in the split function.
Specifically, character classes contain a list of separate characters.

So, `[folder:&]` really matches a single character from the *set* of characters
`'f','o','l','d','e','r',':','&'`

To split on `'&folder:'` or `'&'` or `':'` it should be something like this

```
myfolders = foundedFolders.split(/&?folder:|[&:]+/);
```

Likewise, for `'&file:'` or `'&'` or `':'`

```
myfiles = foundedFiles.split(/&?file:|[&:]+/);
```

Comment: Thanks it workes now :D
I thought that these are characters, but I didn't understood how this could be realizable...

THANKS!!