# PHP: Get string between two character with specific index

Tags: php

I am a beginner of PHP. I have string:

```
$fullstring = "this is [tag]dog[/tag], [tag]cat[/tag], [tag]lion[/tag]";
```

I want to get string `"cat"` from my `$fullstring`.

I used to try with this:

[Get substring between two strings PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php)

But I can only get the first string `(dog)`. Thank you for your time.

Thet Cartter.

Comment: I want to get only "cat"

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: Both solution is naive. You should always check the returned value of `preg_match_all` and `strpos`.

#### Readable regex solution:

Try to use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$fullstring = "this is [tag]dog[/tag], [tag]cat[/tag], [tag]lion[/tag]";

preg_match_all("'\[tag\](.*?)\[\/tag\]'si", $fullstring, $match);

foreach($match[1] as $val){
    echo $val, ' ';
}
// result: dog cat lion
```

To get only the content of the second tag (which is cat now)

```
echo $match[1][1]
// result: cat
```

#### Not readable string split solution:

```php
$fullstring = 'this is [tag]dog[/tag], [tag]cat[/tag], [tag]lion[/tag]';

function get_strings_between(string $string, string $start, string $end): array {
    $r = [];
    $startLen = strlen($start);
    $endLen = strlen($end);
    while (!empty($string)) {
        $startPosition = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($startPosition === false) {
            return $r;
        }
        $contentStart = $startPosition + $startLen;
        $contentEnd = strpos($string, $end, $contentStart);
        $len = $contentEnd - $contentStart;
        $r[] = substr($string, $contentStart, $len);
        $endPosition = $contentEnd + $endLen;
        $string = substr($string, $endPosition);
    }
    return $r;
}

$match = get_strings_between($fullstring, '[tag]', '[/tag]');
// result: dog cat lion
```

To get only the content of the second tag (which is cat now)

```
echo $match[1]
// result: cat
```

Comment: I was about to post exactly same answer. Here's a test  I did http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/g9V It's slightly other pattern, but anyway exact pattern may differ depending on OP case.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `preg_match()` function. An example below may help you out.

```
 $fullString = "this is [tag]dog[/tag], [tag]cat[/tag], [tag]lion[/tag]";
 $regex = "/\[tag\]\w+\[\\tag\]/";
 preg_match($regex, $fullString, $matches);
 foreach($matches as $match){
     echo $match;
 }
 // result, dog, cat, lion
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078259/get-string-between-find-all-occurrences-php/27078384). This function will return all instances it can find based on what you want to search.

```
    function getContents($str, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter, $needle) {
    $contents = array();
    $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
    $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
    $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;
    while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {
        $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
        $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);
        if (false === $contentEnd) {
            break;
        }
        $tempString = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
        if ($tempString == $needle) {
            $contents[] = $tempString;
        }
        $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: to use: getContents($fullstring,'[tag]','[/tag]','cat'); // will return all instances of cat in the string

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify the old function [http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/]. I got this:

```php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end, $index){
    if ($index <= 0) return '';
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = 0;
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= $index) {
      $ini = strpos($string, $start, $ini + 1);
      if ($ini == 0) return '';
      $x++;
    }
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = "this is [tag]dog[/tag], [tag]cat[/tag], [tag]lion[/tag]";
echo get_string_between($fullstring, "[tag]", "[/tag]", 2); // Result = cat
```