# How to get the last occurrence of a string?

Tags: php

I have a function that extracts the content between a $start and $end inside a $string

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

The problem with this is that it will only get me the first occurrence found in the string. Per example:

```
$text = "John has 13 oranges and Jane has 8 oranges";
$how_many_oranges = get_string_between($text,"has "," oranges");
echo $how_many_oranges; // echos "13"
```

I need it to find the last occurrence inside the string, so that $how_many_oranges = "8";

Comment: You could probably just swap out `strpos()` for [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strrpos.php)

Comment: I'm curious about the `$ini == 0` check; why are you doing that? If `$start` is at the very start of the string, `strpos()` will return `0`. Did you instead want to check for `$ini === false`, ie the string cannot be found?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be doing the same thing? ie return "" if not found?

Comment: 0 means found (at the start of the string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, swap out `strpos()` for [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strrpos.php)

> Find the numeric position of the **last** occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

Also, I believe you should change

```
if ($ini == 0)
```

to

```
if ($ini === false)
```

The former will match if `$start` is at the very beginning of `$string`. The latter will match if `$start` cannot be found at all.

Demo ~ https://eval.in/1027283

Comment: Thank you Phil. I've found that it's best to only replace the first strpos() to strrpos() -- replacing both introduces some issues in a number of scenarios. Per example, if $test = "John has 13 oranges and Jane has 8 oranges but they need more oranges", it will no longer give you "8" as result. Replacing only the first one fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

What about using just PHP's built in function?!

**strripos()** – Finds the position of the last occurrence of a string inside another string. It is a Case-insensitive.

[PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strripos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $p1 = explode($start,$str);
    for($i=1;$i<count($p1);$i++){
        $p2 = explode($end,$p1[$i]);
        $p[] = $p2[0];
    }
    return $p;
}
```

source: [stackoverflow.com/a/45033158](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45033158)

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to rewrote your code, to make it, IMHO, more readable and self-explanatory :)

I'd also recommend you to use the [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

```
function getStringBetween($string, $start, $end) {
    $lastStartIndex = strrpos($string, $start);
    $lastEndIndex = strrpos($string, $end);

    $substringStartIndex = $lastStartIndex + strlen($start);
    $substringSize = $lastStartIndex - $lastEndIndex - 1;

    return substr($string, $substringStartIndex, $substringSize);
}

$text = "John has 13 oranges and Jane has 8 oranges";
$how_many_oranges = getStringBetween($text, "has", "oranges");
echo "'" . $how_many_oranges . "'"; // echos "' 8 '"
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a reasonable time to use regular expressions.

```
    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
        $clean_start = preg_quote($start, '/');
        $clean_end = preg_quote($end, '/');
        $pattern = "/.*$clean_start (.*) $clean_end.*/U"; // U modifier => ungreedy
        $default_result = ''; // returned if no matches found
        $matches;
        preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
        return (count($matches[1]) > 0) ? end($matches[1]) : $default_result;
    }

echo get_string_between('John has 13 oranges and Jane has 8 oranges', 'has', 'oranges'); // 8
```