# Get all occurrences of a string between two delimiters in PHP

Tags: php, string, function, strpos, stripos

I am using a PHP function to get all content between two delimiters in a string. However, if I have multiple occurrences of the string, it only picks up the first one. For example I'll have:

```
|foo| hello |foo| nothing here |foo| world |foo|
```

and the code will only out put "hello."
My function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = stripos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = stripos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Comment: What arguments are you calling with? What is the expected result?

Comment: You have no loop in your code. How do you expect it to return multiple things?

Comment: String position functions only return the first occurrence they find. You might want to look into regular expressions.

Comment: You can use `strripos()` to find the last occurrence of a string. Use that to find `$end`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get string between - Find all occurrences PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078259/get-string-between-find-all-occurrences-php)

Comment: @El_Vanja I get this, Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `preg_match_all` and keep things simple:

```
$input = "|foo| hello |foo| nothing here |foo| world |foo|";
preg_match_all("/\|foo\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|foo\|/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => world
)
```

Comment: I feel `|foo|` might be the delimiter, judging by _and the code will only out put "hello."_

Comment: @El_Vanja Well then I guess my original answer was foobar LOL!

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but here's my two cents:

```
<?php 
function between($string, $start = '|', $end = null, $trim = true){
  if($end === null)$end = $start;
  $trim = $trim ? '\\s*' : '';
  $m = preg_split('/'.$trim.'(\\'.$start.'|\\'.$end.')'.$trim.'/i', $string);
  return array_filter($m, function($v){
    return $v !== '';
  });
}
$test = between('|foo| hello |foo| nothing here |foo| world |foo|');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I get no output when it runs.

Comment: Wait, sorry. I just forgot to click run. lol

Comment: `print_r($test);`