# How to find multiple values between two character in a string - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a string that I am trying to retrieve a value from between two certain characters. I know there are multiple questions like this on here, but I couldn't find one that searches for multiple instances of this scenario in the same string.

Essentially I have a string like this:

```
'(value one is: 100), (value two is:200)'
```

and I want to return both 100 and 200. I know that I can write a regex to retrieve content between two characters, but what is the best way to have a function iterate over the string for the `:` character and grab everything from that until the `)` character and only stop when there are no more instances?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, you can use `regex` to get the numbers from string.

```
var str = '(value one is: 100), (value two is:200)';
var regex = /\d+/g;
str.match(regex);
```

Here `\d+` will match the numbers from string. `g` is global flag to match all the elements and not the only first.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k96y3evL/

Comment: if I have multiple values then how can I use substring consider i have string like this `'this is an example of <how><i have it>'` and i need to find values between '<' and '>' this

Answer (score 0):

Using **Regex**

```
var regex = /\d+/g;
var string = '(value one is: 100), (value two is:200)';
var match = string.match(regex);
alert(match);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5xtLbztb/)