# Get the string between 2 different characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a string between 2 characters:

```
"<p>This is some text</p> and then this is some more"
```

How could we get only "This is some text"

Comment: Those are two tags/elements right?

Comment: Do you want to fetch string between tags i.e 'p' tag

Comment: what is meant by 2 characters ? you mean p tag..

Comment: Yes the 2 characters are "<p>" and "</p>"

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript

Comment: `<p>` is 3 characters. `</p>` is 4 characters. Perhaps you mean "between 2 strings"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str="<p>This is some text</p> and then this is some more";
var p=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("<p>")+3,str.lastIndexOf("</p>"));
console.log(p);
```

In Case there are more than one occurrence of the tag use this:

```js
// here `/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g` will give string like <p>This is some text</p> with p tags then replace p with '' using `/<\/?p>/g,''`.
var str="<p>This is some text</p> and then this is some more.<p>hello</p>";
var p = str.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).map(function(val){
   return val.replace(/<\/?p>/g,'');
});

console.log(p);
```

As per `RobG` suggestion if you can possibly construct html with the string then you can try this:

```js
 var p = $('p').map(function(){
       return this.innerHTML;
    }).get();

    console.log(p);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="para">This is some text</p> and then this is some more<p>hello</p>
```

Another similar version of the above with `html()` function.

```js
  var p = $('p').map(function(){
           return $(this).html();
        }).get();

        console.log(p);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p id="para">This is some text</p> and then this is some more<p>hello</p>
```

Comment: Excellent. I was just about to ask about multiple instances. Thank you.

Comment: It is well documented that parsing HTML with regular expressions is not a good idea, see [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...
HTML:

```
<p id="para">This is some text</p> and then this is some more
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("para").innerHTML;
alert(text);
</script>
```

Comment: but everything is a string. The site has been extracted as one long string,

Comment: But this does highlight that parsing HTML using a regular expression is bound to fail, because HTML does not have regular patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
var text = />(.+)</.exec("<p>This is some text</p> and then this is some more")[1]
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said in a comment that "*The site has been extracted as one long string*", then the most robust way is to parse the site back into a document and use DOM methods, e.g.

```js
var s = "<p>This is some text</p> and then this is some more";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;

console.log(div.querySelector('p').textContent); // This is some text
```

Using a regular expression (or series of regular expressions) is bound to fail as HTML is not a regular language and regular expressions are of insufficient complexity to parse it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get text of tag then use following code :

HTML Code

```
<p id="para">This is some text</p> and then this is some more
```

JQuery Code

```
var text = $("#para").text();
```

text gives you text of `<p>` tag