# Extract Video Id From YouTube URL

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

If given the following link to a YouTube video:

`https://youtu.be/PqkaBUmJpq8?list=PLmmPGQQTKzSZSPd3pa6q9UQ-PkeCx1fam`

Is it possible to extract the `video id` from it that gets used in the [YouTube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up writing this function:

```
function extractVideoIdFromYouTubeUrl (url) {

    var stepOne = url.split('?')[0];
    var stepTwo = stepOne.split('/');
    var videoId = stepTwo[stepTwo.length-1];

    return videoId;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function extractVideoIdFromYouTubeUrl(url) {
  let id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("v=")+2,url.length);
  return id;
}
```

This solution assumes that the video ID is at the end of the URL.
I would only advise using it for simple situations like where I needed it, [where the user can't enter a URL, and the Youtube Player API creates a limited possible set of URLs](https://codepen.io/jhancock532/pen/KRxQNb).