# Get words in String Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regex expressions. I want every word in string between two character. have already tried followings Stack Questions:

1. [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript)
2. [Regular expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript)

but nothing working for me i am missing something for sure. but confused what.

```
Suppose a "string": /path/__mutation/module1/__resolver/module2
Get directories between character: "__" and "/" // console.log() => [mutation, resolver]
```

But trying above two questions anwser to construct something which can get all special directories like mutation, resolver in over path.

Following are what i have tried.

```
var __path = /path/__mutation/module1/__resolver/module2

1. console.log(__path.match(/__(.*)?\//g))
// [ '__mutation/login/withMobileNumber/' ]
// [ '__mutation/register/withMobileNumber/' ]
// [ '__mutation/raw/__mutation/register/__resolver/rock/' ]

2. console.log(__path.match(new RegExp(`__` + '(.*)' + `/`)))
// null
consider `Template_String` as variable with those symbols
...
```

Comment: share what you got so far so we can explain what is wrong

Comment: __path.match(/(?<=::\s+).*?(?=\s+\/)/gs) this one

Comment: __path.match(`__` + '(.*)' + `/`)

Comment: Did you try `/__(.*?)\//g`?

Comment: yes this one two...sorry for not elaborated question

Comment: I updated it. It was wrong

Comment: i need solution  :**(

Comment: you want the folders that start with `__`?

Comment: yes exactly folders with __ in [folder1, folder2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split on '/' and then filter on /^__.+/, then map to trim:

```
let path = '/path/__mutation/module1/__resolver/module2'
path.split(/\//).filter(p => /^__.+/.test(p)).map(p => p.replace(/__/,''))

// yields:  (2) ["mutation", "resolver"]
```