# how to get specific characters between others in a string with jquery?

Tags: javascript

Having a string such like this one:

```
var str = "https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/venta/departamento/vitacura-metropolitana/6579-parque-arboleda-nva";
```

I need to be able to only get "6579" number from that string, because it is an ID I need to use. In fact, 
this ID is always located between that last "/" and the next "-" that follows.

So considering that the url is dynamic but this "ID" is always between these two characters "/" and "-", I have to be able to always get the ID.

Any Idea how could I solve this?

I tried with this but

```
var id = str.lastIndexOf('/');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match digits, followed by a dash and making sure anything after it is not a slash.

```js
var str = "https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/venta/departamento/vitacura-metropolitana/6579-parque-arboleda-nva";
console.log(str.match(/\/(\d+)-[^/]+$/)[1])
```

Comment: This is the best approach IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a regexp.

```
'"https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/venta/departamento/vitacura-metropolitana/6579-parque-arboleda-nva"'
  .split('/').pop()
  .split('-').shift();
```

`pop()` removes the last element.

`shift()` removes the first element.

Comment: Love the `.pop` and `.shift` approach, never seen that before for a regex lookbehind/lookahead substitute! +1

Answer (score 0):

Take your var id and substr your original String

```
var index = str.lastIndexOf('/');
var id = str.substr(index+1,4);
```