# How to extract question mark surrounded texts into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string like this,

```
var str = " This is a ?sample? text to ?extract? question marks separated texts into an array in ?Javascript?. "
```

I want a javascript array as below,

```
arr = {
        'sample',
        'extract',
        'Javascript'
      }
```

Comment: This is fairly basic and therefore might not get the best reception. Assuming you don't know where to begin, I suggest you take a quick regex tutorial, which should make solving this task trivial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: "Please make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed."

see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/199263)

Comment: Should `"foo??bar"` output `[]` or `['']` ?

Comment: What should be the output of `"?hello?world?"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternate between keeping and ignoring letters each time you get to a "?". This will not include the text after an opening `?` if there is no closing `?`.

```js
let str = "This ?? should ?only? leave ?four words? ?in? the ?result?. Ignoring if there is no ? closing question mark"
let result = []
let openingQuestionMark = false

let substring = ""

for (let key of str) {
  if (key === "?") {
    if (openingQuestionMark) {
      substring && result.push(substring)
      substring = ""
    }
    openingQuestionMark = !openingQuestionMark
    continue
  }

  if (openingQuestionMark) {
    substring += key
  }

}


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the results having an odd index :

```js
// After the split('?'), an array will be created. One needs the odd indexes
//                0        1         2      3                         4                                 5      6  7
const str = " This is a ?sample? text to ?extract? question marks separated texts into an array in ?Javascript?. ?";

const arr = str.split('?').filter((word, index) => index % 2 !== 0 && word !== '');

console.log(arr);
```

This will be working **only** if you are sure that the input contains only an even number of `?`. An input like `"foo?bar"` will output `[ 'bar' ]`.

To make sure this work with any input, you can use RegEx :

```js
function getWordsBetweenParenthesis(input)
{
  const pattern = /(?:\?)(.*?)(?:\?)/gm;
  const matches = input.matchAll(pattern);
  return [...matches].map(arr => arr[1]);
}

console.log(getWordsBetweenParenthesis(" This is a ?sample? text to ?extract? question marks separated texts into an array in ?Javascript?. "));
console.log(getWordsBetweenParenthesis("foo?bar"));
console.log(getWordsBetweenParenthesis("foo??bar"));
console.log(getWordsBetweenParenthesis("?hello?World?"));
console.log(getWordsBetweenParenthesis("?hello??World?"));
```

Comment: @str indeed, let me tweak that

Comment: @str this requires clarification to OP, if empty string should be excluded or not