# How to target and style a word between two characters within a string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I use javascript to find a word in a string which is wrapped in parenthesis, and then style this particular word. I would like users in a CMS to wrap any word they would like in parenthesis, which would then automatically make this word bold. I know I can get them to wrap the words in  tags but I would like to make it easier for them.

For example, if I had the string

```
Hello (World)
```

How do I target the characters in between the parenthesis and style these characters, so it looks like this.

```
Hello <b>World</b>
```

Comment: `targetElemtn.innterHTML=str.split("(").join("<b>").split(")").join("</b>")`

Comment: `.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, '<b>$1</b>')`. However, this requires html-escaping *before* doing the bolding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`targetElemtn.innterHTML=str.split("(").join("<tag[+attrs]>").split(")").join("</tag>")

```js
function go() {
  var target=document.getElementById("target");
  var input=document.getElementById("input").value;
  var opener=document.getElementById("opener").value;
  var closer=document.getElementById("closer").value;
  target.innerHTML=input
    .split("(").join(opener)
    .split(")").join(closer)
  ;
}
```

```html
<h3>Replace parentheses with tag</h3>
Input: <input id="input"><br>
Tag opener: <input id="opener"><br>
Tag closer: <input id="closer"><br>
<button onclick="go()">Go!</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Try `<b>` + `</b>`, `<span style="color:red">` + `</span>`...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
form.onsubmit = () => {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, '<b>$1</b>');
  return false;
};
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <textarea style="width:100%" name="textarea" id="textarea">Hello {world}! Hello {world}! Hello {world}!</textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for the whole string for parenthesis and replace those with code which will make inner code bold.

```
let str = "Hello (world)"; 
str = str.replace("(","<strong>");
str = str.replace(")", "</strong>");
```

This will only work if updating will also invoke rendering process in browser.