# Get multiple substring between two characters javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring, lastindexof

I'm taking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript) as reference where they suggest this solution:

Current

```
Str = 'MyLongString:StringIWant;'
```

Desired Output

```
newStr = 'StringIWant'
```

Solution

```
var mySubString = str.substring(
    str.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, 
    str.lastIndexOf(";")
);
```

but what if i have multiple incidence? in my case i have a long text, lets say:

```
str = 'MyLongString has :multiple; words that i :need; to :extract;'
```

New desired output:

```
strarray = ["multiple","need","extract"]
```

When i apply the suggested solution its just getting the last word "extract"

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it, running a loop from start of the string to the end and using `indexOf` and `substring` to get the desired result

```js
const str = 'MyLongString has :multiple; words that i :need; to :extract;';

function extractWords(str) {
    const words = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) === ':') {
            const stopIndex = str.indexOf(';', i);
            if (stopIndex !== -1)
                words.push(str.substring(i + 1, stopIndex));
        }
    }
    return words;
}

console.log(extractWords(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

The linked suggestion is actually using a string function instead of a regular pattern; a simple pattern like `/:\w+;/g` gives us all desired words, thanks to the `/g` flag.

We can get rid of the pre- and postfix using [lookarounds](https://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1), however, those may not work in all JavaScript environments (but actually it is less of a problem now since all major browsers support the lookbehind `(?<=..)` operator in their latest versions, and the lookahead `(?=..)` is supported since forever).

```js
str = 'MyLongString has :multiple; words that i :need; to :extract;'
let result = str.match(/:\w+;/g) || [];
console.log(result);

let result2 = str.match(/(?<=:)\w+(?=;)/g) || [];
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: It worked with this example, what if i want to look for substring between "[" and  "]" 
would this work? let result2 = str.match(/(?<=\[)\w+(?=\])/g) || [];

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez yes, however, you may need to escape certain regex special characters like brackets using backslashes, e.g. `(?<=\[)\w+(?=])`

Comment: `(/(?<=\[)\w+(?=\])/g) || [];` its not working, em i missing something?

Comment: Not sure what's 'not working' but the regex is fine, see: https://regex101.com/r/x0mtg8/1/

Comment: This code will work for all. 
let result2 = str.match(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/g)