# Get specific letters between two symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the letters between two specified symbols.

Example

```
var a = 'Testing code https://example.com/ABC-BAC tralala';  // I would need to get ABC
var b = 'Depends on x \n https://example.com/CADER-BAC';  // I would need to get CADER
var c ='lots of examples: \n example.com/CAB-BAC'; // I would need to get CAB

var d ='lots of examples: \n https://abc.example.com/CAB-BAC'; // I would need to get CAB
```

My main problem is that I need a unique syntax that would work for both https:// version or without any https://, therefore using indexOf on '/' wouldn't work that well.

I've tried regex but of course, that only fits one solution:

```
 let regex = /^https://example\.com/[a-zA-Z]+-BAC$/i;
 return regex.test(input);
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into using Regex with matching?

Comment: @Glubus My knowledge on regex is way too limited for this unfortunately, I've tried that in the begining

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: Where are these strings coming from? Are they in `<a>` elements on your page, text..?

Comment: they are simple strings, not html elements. I'm writing some code for a node.js server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `match` here:

```js
var input = "https://example.com/CADER-BAC";
var code = input.match(/^.*\/([^-]+)-.*$/);
console.log(code[1]);
```

Comment: `input.match(/^.*\/([^-]+)-.*$/);` - and what is this dark, magical string? Bear in mind the OP's statement: "*My knowledge on regex is way too limited for this unfortunately...*"

Comment: The current code works for that simple url but will not work for preceding words or \n before the actual url, please see the edited question.

Comment: I made it work for precending words by removing ^ . Thank you for your initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) in combination of [str.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf):

```js
const a = 'Testing code https://example.com/ABC-BAC tralala'; // I would need to get ABC
const b = 'Depends on x \n https://example.com/CADER-BAC'; // I would need to get CADER
const c = 'lots of examples: \n example.com/CAB-BAC'; // I would need to get CAB

const getSubstring = (str) => {
  return str.substring(
    str.lastIndexOf('example.com/') + 'example.com/'.length,
    str.lastIndexOf('-'))
}

console.log(getSubstring(a), getSubstring(b), getSubstring(c))
```