# Remove second part of string with split()

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with a string, let's say this one, which I then display on a page on the site:

```
let value = "qwe asd — bensound summer";

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = value;
```

And I want to remove its second part when displaying this line on the page `bensound summer` along with a dash `—`.

And in order to receive only the first part, which is before the dash, when displayed on the page, in the form: `qwe asd`.

I read about str.split() but didn't find anything like it and didn't quite understand how it all works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Substring between two characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867835/get-substring-between-two-characters-using-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the split method

```js
let value = "qwe asd - bensound summer";

value = value.split('-')[0] // 

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = value;
```

Comment: I discovered that the symbol you are using is not the same try using this `"—" == "-"`  in the console you'll get `false`

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this:

```
let value = "qwe asd — bensound summer";
let splittedString = value.split("-");

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = splittedString[0];
```

Hope, it helps!!