# How to target a specific part of string?

Tags: javascript, string

returns the index where pattern starts in string (or -1 if not found). 
The search is to be case sensitive if the 3rd parameter is true otherwise it is case insensitive.

```
Examples
index("abAB12","AB",true) returns 2 but index("abAB12","AB",false) returns 0
index("abAB12","BA",true) returns -1 and index("abAB12","BA",false) returns 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "target the middle part"? What is this function supposed to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery or JavaScript equivalent of PHP strpos function to find string on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978204/jquery-or-javascript-equivalent-of-php-strpos-function-to-find-string-on-a-page)

Comment: @FelixKling I want to see if the AB is in the first part of the string

Comment: "First part" means the first half of the string?

Comment: @FelixKling first part means "abAB12"

Comment: Ah, so you simply want to know whether a string is contained in another string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: This question is unclear.  Please describe your actual requirements for this function.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried so far? We can help you fix your code, but we are not going to write the code for you. Anyways, the question I linked to should actually solve your problem.

Comment: var input = index("abAB12","AB",true);

if(input.indexOf('"') == -1);
{
  alert("found");
}

Comment: It seems you are asking for implementation of `index`, aren't you? If so you should post the implementation you have so far. I cannot see how the code you posted in the comment is an attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: ye Im not truly sure how to do it. Any hint would be great. I get the procedure just not sure how to put it into code terms.

Comment: As I said, have a look at the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
var str = "abAB12";
var i = str.indexOf("AB");
if (i < str.length / 2) {
  //stuff
} else {
  //other stuff
}
```

Comment: the thing is I need to take the information out of the string not hard code it into it, if you get what I mean.

Comment: @Elliott: This doesn't seem to match with your statement given in an other comment where you said "I want to see if the AB is in the first part of the string". You really should edit your question and describe your problem properly. Right now we are merely guessing.